# Building custom Spring config tags for a framework

Tags: java, spring

I have a framework which currently requires pretty verbose setup in Spring:

```
   <bean id="dpHibernateRemotingAdapter"
            class="org.springframework.flex.core.ManageableComponentFactoryBean">
            <constructor-arg value="org.dphibernate.adapters.RemotingAdapter" />
            <property name="properties">
                    <value>
                            {"dpHibernate" :
                            {
                            "serializerFactory" : "org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory"
                            }
                            }
    </value>
            </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataAccessService" class="org.dphibernate.services.SpringLazyLoadService"
            autowire="constructor">
            <flex:remoting-destination />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dpHibernateSerializer" class="org.dphibernate.serialization.HibernateSerializer"
            scope="prototype">
            <property name="pageSize" value="10" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dpHibernateDeserializer" class="org.dphibernate.serialization.HibernateDeserializer"
            scope="prototype" />
```

I'd like to look at providing a more elegant configuration tag, similar to user-friendly tags used elsewhere in spring:

```
 <context:annotation-config />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <tx:annotation-driven />
 <flex:message-broker/>
```

etc.,

However, I don't really know where to start.

How does this approach work? What are these tags called?  What's their base class?

If someone could point me to the class names in the source (ideally, the `<flex:message-broker />`, as that's the closest problem set to my project), then I can go from there.  I just don't really know where to start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom XML namespaces are certainly possible ([see Appendix D](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html)), but in my experience a royal pain to get working properly.

I strongly recommend that instead you use [`@Bean`-style configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). This lets you use Java to compose your bean graphs, instead of XML. Not only can it be much more concise in certain situations, it's properly type-safe, and more easily re-used.

Either way, you'll end up writing some Java that wires objects together. It's a question of how you want to expose that.

Comment: Thanks for that.  As this is a framework for others to use, I should probably investigate both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

See [Appendix D. Extensible XML authoring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html).