# Spring application context XML macros

Tags: spring, macros

Is it possible to define a macro in my Spring application context XML file that i can use repeatedly to produce similar bean blocks just with different id prefixes and property values?

I'm using the Quartz scheduler which requires to define helper beans for each job. I'm also using bean delegation described [here](http://www.harinair.com/2008/01/spring-quartz-and-auto-wiring-of-quartz-jobs/) which requires even more bean definitions for a scheduled job, so it would be nice if could define a job with something like this:

`<jobs:scheduleJob prefix="someJob" class="this.is.my.Class" cronSetting="0 0 * * * ?" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom schema with Spring. This thread discusses it and provides references [Building custom Spring config tags for a framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263037/building-custom-spring-config-tags-for-a-framework).

Comment: Thank you, this is what i'm searching for.